# Draw indentation guides at each indent of an <li>

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to draw an indent guide (U+250B) at every indent of an element in a `<li>`? For example, I'm working with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar88e/2/) and would like to have an indent guide drawn to the left of Child 1, Child 2, and two guides to the left of Child Child 1 (as it is two indents deep).

I'm open to either a Javascript or CSS solution, but I would prefer CSS if the solution is simpler.

Comment: You shouldn't start from scratch. Start from `<detail>`/`<summary>` (with polyfill) and modify that.

Comment: IDK if I got you, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Ar88e/4/, is somethink like this, but with U+250B instead of border?

Comment: @bjb568 for backwards compatibility reasons, this solution is the one I've created. Additionally, there was no existing solution that encapsulates all of the features I needed, so I made my own.

Comment: @enapupe, that's pretty much exactly it. Thanks! The solution is great, and I think I could just use a dotted border instead of using the unicode character in this case.

Comment: I'm just saying that the markup looks ugly. Fine, start from scratch with detail/summary, but try to keep it semantically correct.

Comment: Oh, and what's `<script type="text/html">`?

Comment: @bjb568 it's a knockout.js template. The markup is unfortunately the best it could have been given what I was working with.

Comment: @Seiyria cool, you may change to dashed and 2px, I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Oh god, oh god. That library looks _awful_. It's a whole other language crammed into HTML/JS. And, no. It's not very good semantically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add margin to all ULs but not the first, then, add padding-left to move the content away from the border and add border-left to the UL.

```
ul {margin:0 40px;border-left:3px dashed black;padding-left:20px}
#nav-bar > ul {margin:0;border:0}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ar88e/6/

Comment: Thanks! I did end up tweaking this a little bit to get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar88e/8/), but overall the idea was fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

use the `:before` pseudo class

```
li li:before {
    content:'\250B';
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
li li li:before {
    content:'\250B\250B';
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar88e/5/)

Comment: This will require me to add new entries to the CSS file any time I go a level deeper, so this doesn't really work out so well. Additionally, the `:before` content doesn't line up with the words above it.

Comment: just modify the css to do it for all levels, this was just a quick show. and as for alignment just use paddings and margins.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it with a flexible css style to effect any li inside of the `#nav-bar ul`.

Here is the css:

```
#nav-bar ul li {
    border-left: 1px dotted black;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar88e/12/)

Fiddle with set width on lis: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar88e/9/)